# cakephp - Can a behavior requires other behavior?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building a custom behavior, but i need to use the Containable behavior within it. Is there any way to ensure that if i use my custom behavior, the Containable behavior is also used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the behavior within your behavior like so:

```
public function setup(Model $model, $settings = array()) {
    if (!$model->Behaviors->enabled('Containable')) {
        $model->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        // or throw an exception letting user know its required to do it manually
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need to do. I’d imagine you can either extends the `ContainableBehavior` class, or load it.

Comment: Am not sure if i would like to extends from it, but i certainly would like to load and use it. I might check how good is to extend from it. Actually if i extends from the ContainableBehavior, wouldn't the 'contain' method clash if both my custom behavior and ContainableBehavior are used?

Comment: I think if you extended `ContainableBehavior`, you wouldn’t need to add it to your `$actsAs` array at all.